# JAVA Guava/collections : How to use a predefined list as a predicate to sort another list by?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, guava

So I have a list like this ['A', 'Z', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'H', 'C'], I do something (this something is for the purpose of this question unchangeable) I get a return of [{id:D, num:5},{id:A,num:5}, {id:C,num:3}, {id:Z,num:3}] I want to keep the fact that it's sorted by the num field, and the return is ALWAYS going to sort by the num field already. But now I want to do a sort within that sort to preserve the original list order, so that my wanted output is :

[{id:A, num:5},{id:D,num: 5},{id:Z, num:3},{id: C, num:3}]

I'm not very good with fluentiterables/guava or the like but I feel like those are the way to go. Can anyone give me a solid example for this?

Comment: Basically what I did was transform the second list into a map and did iterated through the original checking if the second list contains it or not, then inserting into a third list. What happens with this is that I manage to preserve the original ordering but now lose the order by the count (num) It seems like I can do one or the other, but doing both I'm lost.

Answer (score 3):

For the purpose of using a predefined list as sort order, there is [`Ordering.explicit(List)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#explicit(java.util.List)). You can combine this with [`Ordering.onResultOf(Function)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#onResultOf(com.google.common.base.Function)) to sort your output list by the id field.

To combine the sorting by num field with the sorting by id field, you can use [`Ordering.compound(Comparator)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#compound(java.util.Comparator)).

So the complete definition of the desired `Ordering` instance would look roughly like this:

```
Ordering.natural().onResultOf(extractNumFunction)
        .compound(Ordering.explicit(inputList).onResultOf(extractIdFunction))
```

Maybe you need to add generic type information.

You can then use this `Ordering` instance as argument to [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)), or use methods like [`Ordering.sortedCopy(Iterable)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#sortedCopy(java.lang.Iterable)).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Guava to solve this problem, then you may use the `Ordering` class. It is basically an augmented `Comparator`. More specific, it offers the following things that are used in the example below:

- Specify a custom sort order defined by a `List` of elements
- Don't compare elements directly, but compare the result of a `Function` applied to the elements
- Create a compound `Ordering` from several other `Orderings`, so if the first returns `0` try the next in the chain ...

So, you can combine the DESC ordering for the `num` property with a custom ordering for the `id` property, like so:

```
List<String> keys = ImmutableList.of("A", "Z", "D", "E", "B", "H", "C");

List<Map<String, String>> items = ImmutableList.of(
    ImmutableMap.of("id", "D", "num", "5"),
    ImmutableMap.of("id", "A", "num", "5"),
    ImmutableMap.of("id", "C", "num", "3"),
    ImmutableMap.of("id", "Z", "num", "3")
);

Ordering<Map<String, String>> numOrdering =
    Ordering.natural().reverse().onResultOf(item -> item.get("num"));
Ordering<Map<String, String>> idOrdering =
    Ordering.explicit(keys).onResultOf(item -> item.get("id"));

Ordering<Map<String, String>> compoundOrdering = numOrdering.compound(idOrdering);

List<Map<String, String>> result = compoundOrdering.sortedCopy(items);

System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a comparator to sort the elements with same `num`. This comparator will actually depend upon the first list.

First convert your first list  `['A', 'Z', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'H', 'C']` to map.

```
 map - > [A,1] [Z,2] ......[C,7]
```

Once you get the sorted list like

```
 list -> [{id:D, num:5},{id:A,num:5}, {id:C,num:3}, {id:Z,num:3}]
```

Follow this:

```
result;
currentIndex=0;
while currentIndex < list.size()
   currentNum = list.get(currentIndex).getNum();
   while(currentIndex < lis.size() && list.get(currentIndex).getNum() == currentNum)
          add current item to currentList
          currentIndex++;
   Collections.sort(currentList,new CustomComparator());
   result.addAll(currentList)
```

Your comparator will be :

```
  int compare(obj1,obj2){
     if(map.get(obj1.getId() < map.get(obj1.getId())
         return -1;
     else if map.get(obj1.getId() > map.get(obj1.getId()
          return 1;
     else return 0;
  }
```